# VARCHAR TO DATETIME

Tags: mysql

[image]

> 

This date field is currently varchar. I want it to be datetime. If I change the database type, it only affects the data that will be added after that. How can I change the existing ones?(HeidiSql - MysqlFront)

> What I have trieds is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE ca
ALTER COLUMN download_date_time datetime
```

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,download_date_time,103)
```

> But it didn't happen.

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse a date with a given format.

Comment: I don't think `CONVERT()` is a MySQL function. That's SQL-Server. Which database are you actually using?

Comment: HeidiSql and MysqlFront

Answer (score -1):

First convert the `VARCHAR` value to the format that MySQL can parse by default. Then change the datatype.

```
UPDATE ca 
SET download_date_time = STR_TO_DATE(download_date_time, '%Y%m%d_%H%i%s');

ALTER TABLE ca
MODIFY download_date_time DATETIME;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not happen. All became Null
:(

Comment: I screwed up, I had the output format, not the input format.

Comment: No problem, I had a backup, I imported it again. How can we convert it to datetime

Comment: Didn't you see my correction to the answer? You should not be testing on the production DB, use a test table.

Comment: Error: Incorrect datetime value: '20221207_130125' for function str_to_date

Comment: Fixed it, needed to use `%H` for 24-hour time.